# Getting same or previous data while clicking view button using mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

While clicking on different view button we have got different data but getting same data for every view.

I am getting table with data in that there are multiple users each and every user has view button.when we click on view button will get his details based on id but in my case when we click on particular view button I am getting details of that user but after that i will click another user view button but I am getting previous user details

```
  <td style="text-align:center">
     @Html.ActionLink(
       "View",
       "ViewServiceProviders",
       "Admin", 
       new { ProviderID =  CAH.UserID }, 
       new { @class = "btn-xs btn btn-success", data_toggle="modal", data_target="#empviewModel" }) 
   </td>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Iam getting table with data in that they are multiple users each and every user has view button.when we click on view button will get his details based on id but in my case when we click on particular view button iam getting details of that user but after that i will click another user view buttion but iam getting previous user details

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  And please take time out for a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com//tour) and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com//help)

Comment: That means in each case your 'ProviderID' is same or it is not changing. What is CAH.UserID ? How are you differentiating the ProviderID for each user. Please update with more details..

Comment: The provider is changing when we reload the page

Comment: The provider id is not changing when we click another user view button.And provider id is different